# how to show video in fullscreen if tilted phone

Tags: android

I have a website with lots of video. Currently I am struggling to develop an app version of my website. I am developing the app in android studio and using webview to show the website in the app.

Currently I have two issues related to video playing.

First one is, if I am holding mobile phone in portrait mode, and I play a video. Video plays smooth. But if I tilt the phone to landscape mode, the audio still plays but a new website loads where video is not playing.

Second issue is, I want to achieve when a user tilts the phone from portrait to landscape mode, if a video is playing then it should occupy entire screen of phone. Similar to youtube. If a video is playing in portrait mode and if you tilt the phone then the video occupies entire screen, I want such result.

Sorry for my bad english. Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Fast googling, it gives you anything you need to know.

http://tekeye.uk/android/examples/ui/android-portrait-landscape-screens

So you must just define two layouts, one for landscape, and one for portrait orientation.

Then just handle how it should look in both of them.